# WPF Tabcontrol TabItem high CPU usage

Tags: wpf, mvvm, load, cpu

In my WPF application I have a `TabControl` with three `TabItems`. Each `TabItem` has a `ItemsControl` inside which `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` in a Viewmodel. If I open the first and second `TabItem`, CPU usage is <10%. But when I open my third `Tabitem` the CPU usage increases up to >70% and I don't know why.

My first thought was, that data binding causes this. So i removed any binding from this `TabItem`. But even if the third `TabItem` has no content nor code which is called, the CPU usage is still high. If I switch back to the first and second `TabItem`, the CPU usage goes back to normal.

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1">
        <TabItem Header="Tab1" IsSelected="True">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.504,1.5" StartPoint="0.504,0.03">
                        <GradientStop Color="#f0f0f0" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#DBFFDF" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="60*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="175" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#F0F0F0" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="3">
                    <ScrollViewer IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <view:Overview />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#F0F0F0" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="3">
                    <ScrollViewer IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding OverviewElementCollection}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="Tab2">
            <ScrollViewer IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItemCollection}" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab3">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.504,1.5" StartPoint="0.504,0.03">
                        <GradientStop Color="#f0f0f0" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#DBFFDF" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="60*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="175" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#F0F0F0" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="3">
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#F0F0F0" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="3">
                    <ScrollViewer IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ErrorOverviewElementCollection}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

So I hope you can help me!

Comment: Are there any storyboard or similar animation in the third tab?

Comment: Nope. I will add an example

Comment: Have you noticed anything unusual in the Output (Debug) window? I would also recommend you to click the "Pause" button while the CPU usage is up, and then take a look at the threads window (Debug / Windows / Threads) for a thread which might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Ok Output window only says: Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled. How i can see if a thread causes a problem? I man i know this window but I'm not familiar whit it.

Comment: Ok if I paused the main thread, and the CPU usage is 0. So i guess other threads are not responsible for this high CPU usage. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You can't only pause the main thread...

Comment: Of course I can. I'm able to pause single threads in the Debug/Window/Threads  window.